# Handling System.Web.HttpException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Any request to a non existent file or folder is throwing the following exception on my MVC project;

System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path ... could not be found or it does not implement IController

Important Edit:

I would like to handle this case so that **this exception does not go into my Elmah logs**.

Whatever I do inside global.asax Application_Error goes to Elmah logs

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the exception in the Application_Error() method in *Global.asax*

Just like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812235/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

How about a 404 page?

This would be the last of your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("NotFound", "{*url}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Show404" }
 );
```

Comment: I cant use this while i have my default route which i don't want to remove; 
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }

Comment: Why not? This NotFound route would be the very last route in your list. It has be the last because ASP.NET MVC will match the first route it comes to, and this will match **any** route.