# MVC3 Error handling RegisterGlobalFilters or application_error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I see solutions that use either RegisterGlobalFilters to check for errors or a special application_error.

Now that we have MVC3 with the global filters does that mean that we no longer need to think about coding up some special code in an application_error method? Does global filters and the new ability to work with different kind of exceptions handle everything that people used to code manually in application_error routines?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the Global.Application_Error() handler to capture unhandled exceptions and present a "prettified" page while also logging as much exception detail as possible from the exception and all its inner exceptions. The pattern I've used has been consistent since the advent of ASP.NET web forms in .NET 1.0 but MVC changes the pattern somewhat.

There's a pretty nice article for a global MVC error handler using Application_Error() at http://www.davidjuth.com/asp-net-mvc-error-handler.aspx. This may no longer be as necessary with the advent of MVC3 but I still think there's value in having a global error handler in addition to controller-specific handlers. Another good (but older) article about this is available at [Error Handling in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812235/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc).