# Has error handling in MVC changed since 2009?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Google the phrase 'exception handling asp.net mvc3 Application_AcquireRequestState' leads me to:

[Error Handling in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812235/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc)

But is the best answer of 2 years ago still the best answer? What's changed? There seems to be debate as to what methods to override in the current framework.

Comment: That question is from May 2009, not "early 2008"...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it looks like a lot of the information in that question is inaccurate (some of the inaccuracies were even pointed out in some of the less voted up answers to that question) and/or outdated.

On my machine, using .NET 4, MVC 3, and IIS 7 `HandleErrorAttribute` and custom errors work just fine. It's possible that an earlier version of one or more of those components had a bug or something but I'm not in a position to look it up right now.