# MVC: Show any exceptions thrown on the 'Error' page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, exception

I would like to edit my 'Error' page so that whenever an error is thrown it displays the reason why.

**Instead of the default:**

`Error. An error occurred while processing your request.`

**It would say e.g.:**

`Error. An error occurred while processing your request.`

`Reason: "Unable to connect to database 'MVCDatabase'."`

Is there a way of making it so that the 'Error' view would show this?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812235/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc.  You could call the `HttpServerUtility.GetLastError` method in the View code and render the `Message` property of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom error messages and by using a little designing i.e giving them red colour you can store them as a variable in your model class and then simply show them on your page without breaking the visual layout and flow